# Need to automate connection to ssh using Java

Tags: java, unix

I am using Jsch in java to have a connection established to unix host .I am able to connect to unix host.The problem is still the console and prompt is asking again for password.

Attaching the code.

```
package newcon;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.channels.Channel;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.UserInfo;

public class Conn {

            public static void main(String args[]) {
                String user = "XXXXXX";
                String password = "xxxxxxx";
                String host = "xxxxx";
                int port = 22;
                String command1="ls -ltr";
              try {


                java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
                    //config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                JSch jsch = new JSch();
                    Session session=jsch.getSession(user,host, 22);
                    session.setPassword(password);
                    session.setConfig(config);
                    System.out.println("config:"+config);
                    session.connect();
                    System.out.println("Connected");

                    com.jcraft.jsch.Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
                    ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command1);
                    channel.setInputStream(null);
                    ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

                    InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
                    channel.connect();
                    byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
                    while(true){
                      while(in.available()>0){
                        int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                        if(i<0)break;
                        System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                      }
                      if(channel.isClosed()){
                        System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                        break;
                      }
                      try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
                    }
                    channel.disconnect();
                    session.disconnect();
                    System.out.println("DONE");
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            }
```

Can anyone help me out with wats the publickey and Keyboard interactive password.

so that without giving anyting in my prompt it will get connected to host.
Appreciate some ones help on the above Issue,

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: Can you please share the error logs

Comment: can you please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195464/java-jsch-library-run-command-which-expects-password

Comment: Hi sir, as per the request i have tried but its not working

Answer (score 0):

i cant say its an error log,

still attaching the one which i can see from my console.

Kerberos username [nudayaku]: nuadayaku
Kerberos password for nuadayaku: